# Oracle 11g get user defined matched occurrence by a regular expression

Tags: oracle11g

I'm using Oracle 11g and I would like to use the REGEXP_SUBSTR to match all the occurrences for a given pattern. For example

```
 SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('  -> BSC Area-101202006A, BTS-101300014A, TRX-10; 
 Status = ADD IN ATOLL','([0-9]+\b?){1,}') "GSM" FROM dual
```

the above-mentioned query returns only the first match 101202006 but I would like to return the other occurrences that search and match '30' from both the strings '101202006A' and '101**30**0014A'  and match the regex and pattern of 9 characters and should return 101300014.

Answer (score 0):

`REGEXP_SUBSTR` returns one value. You can use `CONNECT BY LEVEL` to find all matches and then use `like` to filter the rows as you like.

```
WITH t (pat)
     AS (SELECT '  -> BSC Area-101202006A, BTS-101300014A, TRX-10; 
 Status = ADD IN ATOLL'
           FROM DUAL)
SELECT *
  FROM (    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (pat,
                                  '([0-9]+\b?){1,}',
                                  1,
                                  LEVEL)
                      AS "GSM"
              FROM t
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (pat, '([0-9]+\b?){1,}'))
 WHERE GSM LIKE '%30%' AND LENGTH(GSM) = 9
```

[**REXTESTER DEMO**](http://rextester.com/live/LMNE99761)